# Can someone explain to me the following Haskell expression

Tags: haskell, hugs

```
f :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
f i n = n : f (i+2) (n+i)
```

can someone explain to me what it does. i know it returns [0,1,4,9,16..] but i dont understand how and what `n : f` means

Comment: You have syntax errors in your example...

Comment: +1 *THIS* is how to ask a homework question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:` is the "cons" operator and constructs a new list whose head is the value to the left of the operator and whose tail is the value to the right of the operator. Thus `0 : [1, 2, 3]` is the list `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

Check the behaviour of this function, by evaluating `f 1 0` as follows:

```
f 1 0 = 0 : f 3 1
```

i.e. `f 1 0` is the result of creating a new list consisting of `0` at the head and the list returned by `f 3 1` as its tail. Similarly, `f 3 1` is as follows:

```
f 3 1 = 1 : f 5 4
```

i.e. `f 3 1` is the result of creating a new list consisting of `1` at the head and the list returned by `f 5 4` as its tail.

Thus, the function recursively builds up a list. Furthermore, it is infinitely tail-recursive (since it has no terminating condition) and will thus result in an infinitely long list.

As for the initial line, `f :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]`, this indicates that `f` is a function that takes two integers (`Integer -> Integer`) and returns a list of integers (`[Integer]`). Strictly speaking, `f` takes an integer (`Integer`) and returns another function that takes an integer and returns a list of integers (`Integer -> [Integer]`) as a resulting of function currying. This is a concept you will become familiar with as you get into Haskell and other functional programming languages in greater depth.

Answer (score 5):

The code in your question does nothing because it contains a type error and a syntax error.

```
f :: Integer -> Integer --> [Integer]
```

As you can see from the highlighting the last bit is a comment because `--` starts a comment in Haskell. As a consequence, the declared type of `f` is `Integer -> Integer`, which is wrong. To fix this change `-->` to `->`.

```
f i n = n : f (i+2) (n+i]
```

Here you have an opening `(` and then a closing `]`. Obviously that's wrong. To fix this change `(n+i]` to `(n+i)`.

Now that that that's done, here's what the fixed code does:

`:` is a constructor for the list type. `x : xs` is the list which has `x` as its head and `xs` as its tail. `n : f (i+2) (n+i)` gets parsed as `n : (f (i+2) (n+i))` (not `(n : f) (i+2) (n+1)` as you seem to believe). So it creates a list whose head is `n` and its tail is the result of `f (i+2) (n+1)`.